# Trailing percent character after integer value

Tags: vb.net

What's the meaning of the percent characters in this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(50% + 50%)
```

Outputs:

```
100
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters

Comment: It's pointless in this case because whole numbers are `Integer` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link in [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) comment mentions it:

> Literals can also use the identifier type characters (%, &, @, !, #,
> $), as can variables, constants, and expressions.